# Were the Swedish holdings in northern Germany accepting or resentful of their overlord after the Peace of Westphalia?

Tags: sweden, thirty-years-war

It is my understanding that during the 30 Years' War (especially when they first joined), Sweden was seen as liberators and champions of the Protestant cause.

Did this favorable view persist in the [Swedish holdings in northern Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominions_of_Sweden#Continental_Dominions) after the Peace of Westphalia?  Or were the people resentful of the foreign rule?

Was there a noteworthy difference between Catholics and Protestants?

I realize that it's hard to know the opinion of people, but I think it can be gauged by either efforts to integrate more with Sweden, or efforts to gain independence from Sweden.

Were there any notable efforts in either way?  If so, were these by nobles trying to increase their own power, or were they popular in nature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even after the Peace of Westphalia, [Swedish rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_Pomerania) was well-regarded to the extent that it was regarded at all. The problem was that Swedish rulers exerted very little power in Pomerania, where two-seventh of the people still lived in serfdom at this late date, and the rest of the rural poor were not much better off.This was due to the power of the local nobles, who had far more power than their counterparts in Sweden.

The one (positive) exception was large cities such as Straslund and Stettin, which were granted autonomy from the aristocracy, were answerable only to the Swedish crown, and where Swedish rule of law prevailed.

Comment: So basically no one cared?  Local rulers ignored the Swedish crown instead of the HRE crown? General population didn't notice?

Comment: @Sarke:Things were  a bit more anarchic in the HRE than elsewhere. Except in the cities.But most people were rural.